# display username after login in python tkinter entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help, how can one display username on the landing page after login, in a tkinter entry box?
I would be grateful if anyone could help with the code.Thanks

Comment: What code? Show me some code and I'll show you some answers.

Comment: There is absolutely no way for us to help you without more information

Comment: i have tried to post the code but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You lack so much of information !! But as much I understood with this that you probably want to use frame.tkraise() function to show the user name in the window but a clear frame.

So you can use the function above as per your requirements and then get the input provided by the user from the entry and display it through label in next frame.

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.geometry("400x300")
window.title("XYZ")

window2 = tk.Frame(window)
window2['bg']='yellow'
window2.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=500)

window3 = tk.Frame(window)
window3['bg']='lightgreen'
window3.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=500)
 
window1 = tk.Frame(window)
window1['bg']='lightblue'
window1.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=500)
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

button = tk.Button(window1, text = "next_frame", command=lambda : raise_frame).pack() #or you can use grid or place function
```